# Input circuit for GPIO of a 3.3v tolerant microcontroller

Tags: gpio, comparator

The micro controller I'm using detects Low for 0-1.8v and high from 1.9-3.3v.

The level I need to check is if the input if from 0v-5v stay low, 5v-24v go high on the micro-controller pin( above 1.8v).

I cannot use a Voltage divider here as the high range has to work from 5v till 24 while giving an output of 2v-3.3v.

I tried using a basic comparator circuit but here the output becomes Vcc. I need the output to become 2v-3.3v.

Output State needs to be digital and not analog. 
EG:
    0-5v should be **LOW** and 5v-24v should be **HIGH**

I have a 3.3v power source for the micocontroller.

How could this be achieved?

Reference attached for comparator.[image]

Comment: Why does the output need to be analog?

Comment: I'd suggest a voltage divider with a diode clamp to Vcc.

Comment: The output is digital i.e 0-5V - Zero, 5-24v HIGH.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an open collector comparator like a LM339..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsogPg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in marcelm's comment it should be as simple as this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9SvaR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Divide it down such that 5V gives you 1.85V and then add a diode to clamp the result to 3.3V.

As shown the output could hit about 3.5 V worst case but generally the input voltage limits on any 3.3 V part will be Vcc + 0.6V, double check your specific parts datasheet to be certain.

As noted in the comments below, while this should work fine for the vast majority of situations there are some circumstances when it can cause problems. This depends upon the exact nature of the system (power draw on the 3.3V rail, whether 24V can be on when 3.3V is off, actual limits on input voltages etc...) this solution may not work. Trevor's answer above is safer, this is cheaper and simpler when you can get away with it.

Comment: ... I got blasted for that "generally" statement before...

Comment: Also... you can end up powering whatever is attached to that 3.3V if the 24V stays up.

Comment: You're not going to be powering much through a 17k resistor, whether it's an issue depends upon the 3.3V circuits. And I did say to check the specific parts datasheet for the "generally", I can't remember seeing digital inputs that didn't have that condition, analog inputs can be more fussy but it would be a very odd part to not cope with that on a digital pin. I agree your solution is certainly the guaranteed foolproof solution for any situation, my answer has potential issues but would work just as well >90% of the time and is simpler and cheaper. I'd say both have their place.

Comment: I agree with you, just commented I got slammed for a similar answer before. 0.89mA is lots to power a sleeping  3.3V micro which draws uA though and it won't like being pulled up to ~8V much.

Comment: It would be better to use a 3V zener to ground than relying on the micro supply to be there.

Comment: Good circuit and what I'd use, this the way, don't need active parts to scale a voltage. Can I suggest OP further considers (a) increase both resistors to reduce drawn current (no criticism, you're illustrating the idea) to 5x/10x microcontroller input current but not too low and (b) use two series resistors for R1 for Single Point Of Failure protection (depends on signal source and safety requirements of application).

Comment: @TonyM, good points, though I still would not rely on the 3.3V being there...

Comment: @Trevor, well said and good point :-) You're OK if 3V3 rail clamps when off (by nature or design, sometimes happens for free) or if the 24 V signal supply and 3V3 rail have a relationship (same PSU)that has 24V up last and dying first.

Comment: @Trevor, The issue with a Zener is that if the 3.3 V rail isn't there then you probably want to clamp to 0.6 V or less rather than to 3.3 V. The diode to Vcc is safer in that it matches the "normal" (there's that word again) limits for parts input pins.

Comment: @Andrew, no the issue is if the 3.3V is not there the top of that diode will be closer to 8V.... which the micro DEFINATELY will not appreciate.

Comment: @Trevor I was assuming that 3.3V is the power supply to the micro and other supporting devices. In that situation if the 3V3 rail was turned off then the system will attempt to power itself from the diode, assuming the total system power draw is > ~1.5mA (or 150uA if you scale the resistors up by a factor of 10) then the system voltage remains under 3.3V and everything is good. It only goes to 8V if the system power draw is 0. With a Zener if the MCU power goes off then it still gets 3V on an input pin which would be bad.

Comment: @Andrew, yes I know, and if this was TTL I'd say that was not an issue. However, with 3.3V devices when they are off.. they draw basically squat. It's a catch 22. You either risk over powering the device, or powering it with the right voltage through an IO pin.  I think door #2 is least likely to be a problem. Well the 339 route is least likely, but u know what I mean.

Comment: @Andrew, all good points either way though.